# How to send selected row (JSON) in TableView to another View Controller?

Tags: json, swift, api, tableview, didselectrowatindexpath

Hello I'm implement json api from this site https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts

I wanna to view just the elemnet of the cell that user select (by id) in other view controller

how to send the current title, body from select the current index cell

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

print("How should i implement specific id ")
var userBySectionNumber = [(key: Int, value: [User])]()
var userById = [(key: Int, value: [User])]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    configureView()
}

private func configureView() {
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    let url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts"
    fetchUsers(using: url)
}

    func load(with users: [User]) -> Void {
    userBySectionNumber = Dictionary(grouping: users, by: { user in
        user.userId ?? 0 }).sorted(by: { $0.0 < $1.0})
    print(userBySectionNumber)
    userById = Dictionary(grouping: users, by: { user in
        user.id ?? 0 }).sorted(by: { $0.0 < $1.0})
    tableView.reloadData()
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    print(userBySectionNumber)
    return userBySectionNumber.count

    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return userBySectionNumber[section].value.count
  }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection 
 section: Int) -> String? {

    return "Section Number \(userBySectionNumber[section].key)"
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "users",for: indexPath) as? customeCellTableViewCell{
        let user = userBySectionNumber[indexPath.section].value[indexPath.row]
        cell.dataModel(forModel: user)
     return cell
    }
    return UITableViewCell()
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 100}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {



override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {    
}
}

here i fetch the url

func fetchUsers(using url: String){
    let url = URL(string: url)!
    let _ = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url){ (data,response,error)
        in
        guard let data = data else {return}
        do{
            let userFetch = try JSONDecoder().decode([User].self, from: data)
            self.users = userFetch
            self.load(with: userFetch)
        } catch{

            }
        }.resume()
}
```

The question how to show selected row (with id,title and body) and send it in the next view Controller

Answer (score 0):

You can create **User** variable named like *selectedUser* that holds the selected **User**. When you tap any of cell you should assign the selected user to this variable in your **didSelectRowAt** method.

Also in **OtherViewController**:

- Add an **User** variable.

Lastly, in your **prepareForSegue** method:
You should do something like this:

```
self.selectedUser = otherVC.user
```

Answer (score 0):

You can capture the selected **userById** once the row is selected in the **didSelectRow** method like so:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
self.userById = userBySectionNumber[indexPath.section].value[indexPath.row]
}
```

Once you have the selected user object you can pass it using the **prepare(for segue:)** method just like the following:

```
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) { 
 if let nextViewController = segue.destination as? NextViewController {
 nextViewController.userById = self.userById
 }
}
```